# Creating new layout vs. making elements invisible (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app, for instance, when a user creates a new post, he or she can select a type of media (photo, video, text, place, etc.) and then review it in the following activity.

The way I have been doing it is to have all of the views (i.e. `ImageView`, `VideoView`, `WebView`, etc.) there, but set their visibility to invisible, unless the user chooses that type of media.

For instance, all of the views are invisible until the user takes a photo and then only the `ImageView` is visible. This seems wasteful though. Before I start the activity, I know which type of media the user chooses, but still have the invisible, unused views.

Would it be smarter to have separate layouts for each type of media with the repeated elements (the create post button, the privacy and venue buttons, etc.)? But this would violate the DRY principle...

How costly are invisible views? What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: If you set the visibility to GONE then there is no performance cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the `complexity` of the `Layouts`, I had this issue in previous app, in first iteration I did like you, but in 2nd iteration I found its hard to optimise single layout with bunch of invisible views; much less the `if else` cases to toggle views visibility.

and about layout performance, also it depends on layout/design complexity, I don't think unused view will consume that much of memory or cpu.

so if your layout is simple, its okay for now, if not I recommend to use separate layout for each design/type.

---

and as @ashishduh said, the best is to set visibility to `GONE` instead of `INVISIBLE`, since the parent layout will not measure `GONE` views, but this doesn't prevent view usage of memory or cpu (mostly in custom views)